# Last-child style over-rides first-child style when only one child is available

Tags: css, css-selectors

[image]

```
ul li:first-child a {
   border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

ul li:last-child a {
   border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

When there's just once child, the last-child style over-rides the first-child style. Is there a way to apply both (since it is both the first and last child)

Am looking to achieve this with just CSS, without the aid of JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just apply your borders individually:

```
ul li:first-child a {
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:last-child a {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

That way the last-applied rule doesn't override the previous rule (`border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;` resets the bottom border radii back to zero).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vUz5Z/5/

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:only-child`. Just add

```
ul li:only-child a {
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

after them. It won't work in IE8 (or older), but I'm guessing its not an issue, since `border-radius` doesn't work in IE8 either.

Or use the border radius on the list itself `ul {border-radius: 5px}` if that is possible.

Comment: I tried `ul li:first-child a, ul li:only-child a. {border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;}`, but `last-child` overrides `only-child` for me. For some reason, if I separate the CSS classes for first child and only child, then it works.

Comment: Order of rules matter. If you have only one element, the rule at the bottom will apply.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the border radius on the container instead?

```
ul,li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
ul { border-radius: 10px; overflow:hidden }
a { display:block; margin-bottom:2px; padding:3px; background-color:#f00 }
ul li:last-child a {
 margin: 0;
} ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BanEg/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use auto insead of 0px values.
Ex. (LESS):

```
&:first-child{
    .border-radiuses (5px, auto, auto, 5px);

}
&:last-child{
    .border-radiuses (auto, 5px, 5px, auto);
}
```