# CSS first-child and last-child don't work when used on the same element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I just noticed that CSS `:first-child` and `:last-child` don't work when used on the same element. Only one is used. I'm wondering why is that and if there is any workaround to that in CSS? It seems like CSS bug to me - first element can be also last element.

I couldn't find anything in Google on that subject. Each tutorial assumes that there will be at least 2 elements.

I'm looking for something like: "first child is also last child" selector. Does it exist?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> I'm wondering why is that and if there is any workaround to that in CSS? It seems like CSS bug to me - first element can be also last element.

It's not a bug. It's how the cascade works: if an element is both the first child and the last child, then if you have `:first-child` and `:last-child` in *separate* rules and they both match the same element, then anything in the later declared or more specific rule will override the other.

You can find an example of this behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537901/last-child-style-over-rides-first-child-style-when-only-one-child-is-available), with the `border-radius` shorthand property, and workarounds that include using the component properties instead of the shorthand, as well as specifying a separate rule altogether using one of the following selectors...

> I'm looking for something like: "first child is also last child" selector. Does it exist?

Literally, you would chain both pseudo-classes like this, which works fine:

```
:first-child:last-child
```

However there exists a special pseudo-class that acts the same way:

```
:only-child
```

The main difference (in fact, the *only* difference) between these two selectors is specificity: the first one is more specific as it contains one additional pseudo-class. There is no difference even in browser support, as `:last-child` and `:only-child` are both supported by the exact same versions of each browser.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your blazing fast response! It's even better that `:only-child` exists - it adds more flexibility.

Comment: Make sure you are supporting IE9+ as I think that is the first version of IE that supports :only-child.

Comment: @AlexM: Correct. It's also the first version to support `:last-child`. Unfortunately there isn't a way to target the only child using pure CSS in older versions; you'd have to manipulate the HTML or use a script.

Comment: It's also great that `:only-child` exists because you cannot chain the other two in the negation context: `:not(:first-child:last-child)` doesn't grab anything and `:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)` doesn't grab the respective first or last child in a multi-children series.

Answer (score 5):

I realise I'm massively late to this, but you can also use is CSS's `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`. For example:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Some text you want to quote</p>
</blockquote>
```

This CSS will add quotes to the paragraph:

```
blockquote{
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}

blockquote p:first-of-type:before{
  content:open-quote;
}

blockquote p:last-of-type:after{
  content:close-quote;
}
```